# Allow only a single marker on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want the user to place a marker on a Google Map on a page. If the user clicks again, the first marker should disappear, and be replaced by the new one. How would I do this, starting from this code, as provided by Google:

```
function myMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.7, 5), zoom: 6
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map
            });
        });
```

My first attempt was to add `marker.remove();` at the start of the addListener function, this did not work for me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself. Replacing the AddListener with the below worked great:

[GoogleMaps v3 API Create only 1 marker on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684274/googlemaps-v3-api-create-only-1-marker-on-click)

```
var marker;

function placeMarker(location) {
 if ( marker ) {
   marker.setPosition(location);
 } else {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: location,
  map: map
  });
 }
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  placeMarker(event.latLng);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps you in placing the marker when the user clicks. If user clicks again the earlier marker is removed and the new position is marked. My answer aims at rectifying your mistakes in the first try you did. Try this.

```
  var flag=0,marker;
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
  if(flag)
    marker.setMap(null);
  else
    flag=1;
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: e.latLng,
    map: map});
  });
```